# Anaconda Spyder 4.1.5 updates

Tags: windows, ubuntu, anaconda, spyder

I have the most recent Anaconda navigator on both my Windows and Linux machines, but when i open Spyder on either machine it tells me that Spyder 4.1.5 is available and i should install it. I can't do this through navigator.
The Anaconda page says to run 'conda install -c anaconda spyder' to install Spyder 4.1.5. link: [Anaconda.org page](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/spyder) On my linux machine this just tries to install Spyder 4.1.4 [(Ubuntu screeenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoX0P.png), I get the same result with windows [(windows screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuLBe.png)
It seems this is a regular issue, what is the point of relesaing a piece of software and then not allowing it to be downlaoded and installed in the very manner that both Anaconda and Spyder tell you to do it?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please run first `conda update anaconda` and then `conda install spyder=4.1.5`. That should do the trick.

Comment: It did the trick for me.  had the same problem. Thanks @CarlosCordoba !

Comment: So you have to add the version number? I have a similar issue where I am trying to update Spyder to version 5 and it keeps telling me I already have the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have a previous version installed, did you try a simple *update* from  the conda prompt?

```
conda update spyder --dry-run
```

Just remove the --dry-run part if everything looks fine.

Comment: that give me this :  
 (base) C:\Windows\system32>conda update spyder --dry-run  
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done  
Solving environment: -  

Updating spyder is constricted by  

anaconda -> requires spyder==4.1.4=py38_0  

If you are sure you want an update of your package either try `conda update --all` or install a   specific version of the package you want using `conda install <pkg>=<version>`  

done  

# All requested packages already installed.

Comment: apologies, i tried to edit the comment to format it properly, but it won't let me